# Dynamic array expansion on the heap (values disappearing)

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

So I have this assignment to do for a course where I need to use dynamic array expansion instead of vectors. It is driving me nuts because I have already done it a couple of times successfully in the past, and I have been trying to figure out unsuccesfully what was wrong with THIS one for the last 2 days.

In my code, I am trying to double the size of stringsArr every time my array gets full.
My stringsArr initially is of arrCapacity 4 (it's max size), and contains 5 values.
**The stringsArr is a private attribute of my StringSet class.**

I have tried it both using the heap (the way I am supposed to do it for the assignment), and the stack (just as a check).

**printStringsArr():**
I am using this function to print to the console the final array I get:

```
void StringSet::printStringsArr() {
   for (int i = 0; i < arrIndex; i++) {
      cout << i << ": " << stringsArr[i] << endl;
   }
   cout << "\n" << arrCapacity << endl;
}
```

## Heap Implementation (The one that doesn't work):

I added 2 for loops to display the content of my stringsArr, because I do not understand why the content of my stringsArr changes like this when I declare a new array on the heap.

```
if (arrIndex == arrCapacity) {

    int newCapacity = (arrCapacity * 2);

    /* Display content of stringsArr 
     before tmpArray declaration*/
    for (int i = 0; i < arrIndex; i++) {
        cout << "." << stringsArr[i] << endl;
    }
    cout <<  "\n" << endl;


    // Allocate on the heap the new empty array
    string *tmpArr = new string[newCapacity];


    /* Display te content of stringsArr after declaring 
     tmpArr on the heap*/
    for (int i = 0; i < arrIndex; i++) {
        cout << "." << stringsArr[i] << endl;
    }

    // Copy everything
    for (int i = 0; i < arrCapacity; i++) {
        tmpArr[i] = stringsArr[i];
    }

    // Update arrCapacity to its new value.
    arrCapacity = newCapacity;

    delete [] stringsArr;

    stringsArr = tmpArr;
}
```

#### Heap Implementation Output:

```
// From the 1st for loop.
.Dog  
.Cat  
.Turtle  
.Lion

// For the 2nd for loop,
// mysteriously, only the first value is left.
.Dog  
.  
.  
.  

// And for the "printStringsArr()" function.
0: Dog
1: 
2: 
3: 
4: Fish
```

I'm sure that there is something I completely missed, but I just have no idea of what it is...

## Stack Implementation:

```
if (arrIndex == arrCapacity) {

    int newCapacity = (arrCapacity * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrIndex; i++) {
        cout << "." << stringsArr[i] << endl;
    }
    cout <<  "\n" << endl;


    string *tmpArr[newCapacity];


    for (int i = 0; i < arrIndex; i++) {
        cout << "." << stringsArr[i] << endl;
    }

    // Copy everything
    for (int i = 0; i < arrCapacity; i++) {
        tmpArr[i] = &stringsArr[i];
    }

    arrCapacity = newCapacity;

    delete [] stringsArr;

    stringsArr = *tmpArr;
}
```

#### Stack Implementation Output:

```
// From the 1st for loop.  
.Dog  
.Cat  
.Turtle  
.Lion  

// For the 2nd for loop.  
.Dog    
.Cat  
.Turtle  
.Lion  

// And for the "printStringsArr()" function.  
0: Dog  
1: Cat  
2: Turtle  
3: Lion  
4: Fish
```

My big question is "Why do values disappear from my stringsArr after I declare a new empty array on the heap?".
To me, this is black magic so far, and I want to understand why this happens and how to fix it.

Thanks for your help folks.

### EDIT: single file abbreviated code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
class StringSet {
public:
    StringSet() {
        this->arrCapacity = 4;
        this->arrIndex = 0;
    }

    bool insert(string str) {

        // If string already present, return false.
        for (int i =0; i < arrCapacity; i++) {
            if (stringsArr[i] == str) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Otherwise, insert the string at the next available index in our array.
        // If the arrCapacity is less or equal to the next index, increase the array
        // size two-folds.
        // arrIndex always point to the top empty cell of the array.

        // arrIndex points to the next free cell on the array
        if (arrIndex == arrCapacity) {

            int newCapacity = (arrCapacity * 2);

            /* Display content of stringsArr
             before tmpArray declaration*/
            for (int i = 0; i < arrIndex; i++) {
                cout << "." << stringsArr[i] << endl;
            }
            cout <<  "\n" << endl;


            // Allocate on the heap the new empty array
            string *tmpArr = new string[newCapacity];


            /* Display te content of stringsArr after declaring
             tmpArr on the heap*/
            for (int i = 0; i < arrIndex; i++) {
                cout << "." << stringsArr[i] << endl;
            }

            // Copy everything
            for (int i = 0; i < arrCapacity; i++) {
                tmpArr[i] = stringsArr[i];
            }

            // Update arrCapacity to its new value.
            arrCapacity = newCapacity;

            delete [] stringsArr;

            stringsArr = tmpArr;
        }

        stringsArr[arrIndex] = str;


        arrIndex++;

        return true;
    }


    //Dump the content of stringsArr to the console.
    void printStringsArr() {

        for (int i = 0; i < arrIndex; i++) {
            cout << i << ": " << stringsArr[i] << endl;
        }
        cout << "\n" << arrCapacity << endl;
    }

private:
    //ArrIndex shows where the index is at. If it become equal to ArrCapacity (index 2   corresponds to capacity 3, not 2),
    // the array needs to be increased in size.
    int arrIndex;
    int arrCapacity = 0;

    string *stringsArr = new string[arrCapacity];


};


StringSet* objectString = new StringSet;

objectString->insert("Dog");
objectString->insert("Cat");
objectString->insert("Turtle");
objectString->insert("Lion");
objectString->insert("Fish");
objectString->insert("Zebra");
objectString->insert("Human");
objectString->insert("Squirrel");

cout << "\n" << endl;
objectString->printStringsArr();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nothing evident in the code posted, so you need to post a **complete** but **minimal** example that exhibits the behavior. "Complete" means, something that readers can compile and run.

Comment: Can you just post a single C++ file that we can compile and see what's happening? Your code snippet looks correct.

Comment: I have added a single file for my full code @vsoftco

Comment: I have added a single file for my full code @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: Class is defined inside main...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the initialization of `stringsArr` to the constructor body:

```
StringSet() {
    arrCapacity = 4;
    arrIndex = 0;
    stringsArr = new string[arrCapacity];
}
...
string *stringsArr;
```

Without this change `stringsArr` was initialized to `new string[0]`, and later your code had an array index overflow for indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3, overwriting other parts of the heap.

Even better, as long as initialization order is the same as declaration order:

```
StringSet(): arrIndex(0), arrCapacity(4), stringsArr(new string[arrCapacity]) {}
```

Also don't initialize `arrCapacity` and `arrIndex` outside the constructor.